# Why can I not print the last element in my linkedlist

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I have implemented a basic linkedlist, that contains a Node class and a Linkedlist class, the Node class is a java generic.

I am just wondering, why does my last element not print, when I do a print statement here is my classes

Linkedlist.class

```
  /**
 * A linked list is a sequential list of nodes that hold data that point to nodes also containng data
 *
 * Linked lists are used in Lists, Queues and Stacks
 * Great for creating circular lists
 *
 * Head = first node in a linkedlist
 * Tail = last node in a linkedlist
 * Pointer = reference to the next node in a linkedlist.
 * Node = object containing data.
 */
public class Linkedlist<T> {
    Node Head;

    public Linkedlist(Node n)
    {
        Head = n;
    }

    public boolean contains(T obj)
    {

        Node n = Head;
        while (!(n.getNextNode().equals(null))){
            System.out.println(n.getNextNode());  //Last element does not print here
            n = n.getNextNode();
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Node.class

```
 public class Node<T> {

    Node next = null;
    T data;


    public Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
    };

    public void setNext(Node n)
    {
        next = n;
    }

    public Node getNextNode()
    {
        return this.next;
    }

    public T getData()
    {return this.data;}

    public void printNode()
    {
        System.out.println(getData());
    }

}
```

Thank you for the assistance, I am using the contains method to check if my while loop is iterating over all the elements. ( I think it, but it is just stopping at the last element and not going any further).

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Add the programming language to the question tags.

Comment: ahh sorry, it is java

Comment: Java custom is to overload Object.toString(). How can you be sure the argument to `contains()` never is in the `Linkedlist<>`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rethink how you print the data. Currently you never print the data from `Head` node, as you only ever print the next node (`n.getNextNode()`). You are also breaking the loop when the next element is null. This causes the last element to not be printed, as `getNextNode()` will return null before the print call.

Instead go like this:

```
public boolean contains(T obj) {
    Node n = Head;
    do {
        System.out.println(n.getData()); // print data of current node
        n = n.getNextNode(); // move to next node
    } while (n != null); // break if we are behind next node. n is null
    return false;
}
```

or if you might have an empty list (node passed into constructor is null):

```
public boolean contains(T obj) {
    Node n = Head;
    while (n != null) {
        System.out.println(n.getData());
        n = n.getNextNode();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Will fail for an empty list. Loop should begin `while (n != null)`. Also, as written, the code doesn't implement `contains` correctly. Instead, it prints nodes (as does the OP's code).

Comment: I didnt realise i reassign n to the next node in my last line :(((((  
This is what happens when u code at night

Comment: Well, you need to reassign, otherwise the loop will no move forward and would just be an `if`

Comment: @jarmod well, the question was about the printing and not how to correctly implement the `contains` method. So the answer is definitely in the scope of the question